Why do Palestinians in Lebanon seem relatively absent from the Hezbollah - Israeli confrontation?
There are 250,000-400,000 Palestinians in Lebanon.
And there are frequent military and rocket clashes between Hezbollah and Northern Israel.  Those clashes are not necessarily desired by the Lebanese government proper, but they both unable and unwilling to control Hezbollah, which claims to be acting on behalf of Palestinians.
Needless to say, right now, September 2024, we are at a particularly violent phase.
Yet Palestinians in Lebanon rarely figure in coverage of these events.  No doubt one can find links between them and Hamas and other terror groups, but nothing at Hezbollah's scale and almost conventional military means.
Certainly not trying to give anyone any ideas, but it seems curious.  Is it a genuine absence of involvement?  Is their involvement real but limited and/or not much covered by the press? Or are they operating under the Hezbollah umbrella?  Or the reverse:  has Hezbollah ruled out cooperation?  Are they just generally sitting the whole thing out?  Is the Lebanese state actually doing its job and keeping a lid on things?  Do they lack the means to engage in warfare? (but Hezbollah could have armed them).
p.s. Lebanon is famous for its religious rivalries: Hezbollah is Shiite and Palestinians are Sunni.  And Palestinians are not necessarily super appreciated in Lebanon either, which could be a factor.

Good Q. Before the rise of Hezbo, the Palestinian groups were more prominent in the confrontation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_insurgency_in_South_Lebanon

FWTW, there seem to difficulties in forming an alliance https://apnews.com/article/lebanon-islamic-group-mohammed-takkoush-hezbollah-israel-f9fb0e01e8603cb98363b3263928bd69 ; https://carnegieendowment.org/sada/2024/06/quwwat-al-fajr-and-hezbollah-unlikely-allies-against-israel?lang=en So far this has been limited to relatively small groups, AFAICT. (Quwat al-Fajr is Jamaa al-Islamiya's military wing, so the pieces are talking about the same thing, basically.)

Do we have good information as to the family origins of Hezbollah members? You can’t figure this out from someone’s name or looks alone, so it’s quite possible that many fighters are indeed of Palestinian origins.

@JonathanReez I don't think anyone has ever mentioned Hezbollah broadening its fan base much beyond Lebanese Shiites.  They might do it a bit, but unless an answer indicates otherwise, it's probably negligible.

Could there be some mistrust form the palestinian insurgency in Lebanon? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_insurgency_in_South_Lebanon

Hezbollah is allowed to possess weapons by the Lebanese government; Palestinians outside Hezbollah are not, so it's obvious why Hezbollah is the leader of the armed struggle. I'm not sure what the OP is expecting Palestinians to do or asking what they don't do; there's a tradition of people demanding every Muslim condemns everything bad any Muslim does anywhere, and it's not clear if the Q is part of that. "We don't hear much about Palestinians in Lebanon" isn't really valid unless you hear about every other ethnic group in Lebanon, whereas it seems to be pretty much Hezbollah only.

@StuartF "Hezbollah is allowed to possess weapons by the Lebanese government; Palestinians outside Hezbollah are not"  would make a good answer as well.    "There is a tradition of demanding.." - there is indeed, but this question makes no such demand.  "Unless we hear..." this is a really bizarre objection - many Palestinians do have a vested interest in conflict w Israel.  Other groups do not.  The Q is pretty simple:  "Palestinians in Lebanon are not currently attacking Israel as far as I know.  Why is that?"  No more, no less.  (after all, they did in the past)

Some interesting developments. Apparently Israel tried to kill some Fatah leader in a camp (but only got his son) https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/10/1/why-did-israel-attack-lebanons-biggest-palestinian-refugee-camp Also they killed 3 PFLP members in central Beirut.

Hard to say for sure, but despite some reports that Hamas has been recruiting in Lebanon's refugee camps, and strong rhetorical support over there for Gaza etc., it seems they lack any signficant armed organization, of the kind that could pose problems for Israel. It seems likely Hezbollah doesn't find them trustworthy enough to give them serious long-range weapons etc.
The PBS story (first link) does have one interviewee say that Hezbollah trainers provide weapons instructions for Hamas fighters in those camps, at least nowadays.
According to JP/NYT's account (2nd link) few Palestinians joined Hezbollah. Also, the Palestinian camps in Lebanon are still controlled by Fatah. Hamas only operates underground there. Despite some occasional fighting in the camps, Fatah has managed to stay in control.
Another point mentioned in a (pretty long) story in the liberal L'Orient is that Hamas had until a few years ago avoided doing military operations from abroad; this was in part a deliberate departure from PLO policy/history.

“Initially, Hamas maintained a consistent position, vowing not to engage in hostilities from Lebanon, respecting existing laws, and aiming to avoid a repetition of Fatah’s involvement in the Lebanese civil war (1975-1990),” said Hicham Bourgi, a Palestinian researcher closely associated with the PLO.
Ali Amin, a Lebanese analyst with a critical stance toward Hezbollah, is of the same opinion. According to Amin, Hamas did not subscribe to “resistance” outside Palestine. The movement’s leaders consistently emphasized their presence in Lebanon as purely political, disavowing any military intentions.
[...] It wasn’t until April 2023, during another round of rocket launches toward Israel [from Lebanon], that the Israeli army’s Arabic-speaking spokesman Avichay Adraee openly accused Hamas of being behind the attacks.


Small addendum: the  (more or less) Hamas equivalent, i.e. Sunni Muslim Brotherhood affiliate of Lebanon proper--the Jamaa al-Islamiya--has an armed wing called [Quwat] Al-Fajr. These guys have already been fighting on the Hezbollah side, but they too don't seem terribly effective. Reportedly Hamas was instrumental in the rapprochement between this Al-Fajr group and Hezbollah. Also, reportedly, Israel already killed one of the Al-Fajr commanders, in the Bekaa valley (a Hezbollah stronghold). There's been little international press coverage of this though, due to the relative obscurity of the group.

OK, that makes sense, even if it makes for a convoluted read and set of influences.  But it also sounds like the situation is fluid and their relative absence from Lebanon-based attacks is not guaranteed, unless the Lebanese government persists in keeping them down.  And that government isn't known for being in control of very much.

@ItalianPhilosopher: the gov't/army doesn't even enter the camps. The Palestinians (i.e. Fatah for now) police them. The army does have a presence at the entrance to the camps though, which perhaps stops smuggling in large weapons in very overt fashion.

Oh, I know that.  But your links referred several times to the fact that their possession of heavy weaponry is frowned upon by others.  Still, Lebanon 10 years ago was somewhat less disorganized than it is now, so if Hamas is also supplanting Fatah, the Lebanese govt is even less likely to keep a lid on it as before.

@ItalianPhilosopher: there's been a report of small arms being smuggled from Turkey into the camps https://today.lorientlejour.com/article/1414709/army-seizes-two-trucks-smuggling-firearms-into-lebanon-how-bad-is-it.html

Hezbollah is not about the Palestinian cause. Their official goal when started was inter alia “To expel Americans, the French and their allies definitely from Lebanon” While they do look to create constant war with Israel and aspire to destroy it they do not claim to be looking  to create a Palestinian state there. They believe they are fighting a religious war against Jews that would be the case independent of the Palestinians  https://books.google.com/books?id=m_ktBrZfuUYC&dq=theological+hezbollah+jewish&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q=theological%20hezbollah%20jewish&f=false
While he hasn’t kept that promise Nasrallah has also claimed that Hezbollah would not fight Israel outside of a defensive wars.
https://transcripts.cnn.com/show/sun/date/2003-03-16/segment/11
Furthermore Hezbollah  is involved in many other conflicts that have nothing to do with the Palestinians like the Syrian civil war. Say the Israel - Palestine conflict were resolved, Hezbollah would certainly not disband. They would just  look for some other conflicts  to involve themselves in and take on as their cause. As such it isn't an organization for Palestinians  in Lebanon to run to kill and die for

No DV, but this question is about the Palestinians, not about Hezbollah.  I don't doubt that what you say is true, but this question was not about them.  Unless they themselves influence Palestinian behavior to keep from attacking Israel.

@ItalianPhilosopher You ask why Palestinians are absent from Hezbollah-related news, and this answer is that they barely have anything to do with Hezbollah (or that Hezbollah barely has anything to do with them). How does this not answer the question?

This question was expressly worded to ask about what the Palestinians-in-Lebanon (they are not citizens) are up to.  They are not covered in this answer.

@ItalianPhilosopher It would then help to rephrase the title. If focused on Palestinians, albeit in Lebanon, why mix Hezbollah in?


Question:
Why do Palestinians in Lebanon seem relatively absent from the Hezbollah - Israeli confrontation?

Palestinians in Lebanon are absent from the Hezbollah-Israeli confrontation for several reasons, including sectarian differences, historical dynamics, and political circumstances.
Hezbollah is a Shiite Muslim organization backed by Shiite Iran, while the majority of Palestinians are Sunni Muslims. Although Hezbollah and Palestinian groups like Hamas (which is Sunni) share a common enemy in Israel, their sectarian differences limit close cooperation. Hezbollah's focus remains primarily on defending Lebanon's Shiite community and confronting Israel on behalf of its own agenda and that of Iran, while Palestinian groups pursue their distinct goals regarding the Israeli occupation.
The Palestinians in Lebanon have been marginalized politically and socially since the 1980s, especially after the Israeli invasion in 1982 and the subsequent expulsion of the Palestinian Liberation Organization (PLO) from Lebanon. This diminished their influence and military presence in the country.
Today, most Palestinians in Lebanon live in refugee camps and face significant restrictions on their movement and rights, making it difficult for them to organize and participate in militant activities on a large scale. The Lebanese government, wary of the destabilizing influence the Palestinians once had during Lebanon's civil war, has kept them politically marginalized and confined to camps.
Hezbollah operates as a Lebanese nationalist group that primarily aims to protect its base of support in Lebanon, especially among the Shiite population, and to act as a resistance force against Israel. While it occasionally expresses solidarity with the Palestinian cause, Hezbollah’s primary focus is on maintaining its position of power within Lebanon and aligning with Iranian objectives in the broader Middle East.
Hezbollah has its own well-established militia and does not necessarily need Palestinian militants to join its ranks. Its military apparatus is already highly organized, disciplined, and aligned with its strategic objectives.
Palestinian leadership is splintered, with Hamas controlling Gaza and Fatah leading the West Bank. This fragmentation weakens their ability to form a united front or to coordinate their efforts with other actors in the region like Hezbollah. The divisions between Hamas and Fatah also create internal distractions that prevent a unified military or political strategy.
The Palestinian groups in Lebanon have little cohesive leadership or military capability, and any active Palestinian involvement in Hezbollah's operations against Israel could complicate Lebanon's already delicate sectarian balance.
